# Can I create custom function to insert/update that can be reused for many tables in SQLite?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I'm a newbie in iOS and this is my first programming language. I try to create a custom function that can be reused for different tables ( have different number of data fields) in SQLite.

How can I do it? I read many example about SQLite in Objective-C but I couldn't find an answer (or just my search skill are bad). Please help me answer this question or just suggest me how to do, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can make some generic class ,which you can used for any table. By creating one method, which accepts dictionary and query string.

But I suggest you to not to do that. Instead create separate class for each table.

And in that class, each method only accepts dictionary.

So that class will be wrapper for the other developer(if any for your project) so they do not need to think about any query. Just call method and pass dictionary.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Angel Vasa

Comment: But can you give me an example about how to do that? I just want to learn about it.